# Intersection of two collections of different objects types java 8

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists of objects:

```
List<SampleClassOne> listOne;
List<SampleClassTwo> listTwo;
```

SampleClassOne:

```
public class SampleClassOne{
  private String myFirstProperty;
  //ommiting getters-setters
}
```

SampleClassTwo:

```
public class SampleClassTwo{
  private String myOtherProperty;
  //ommiting getters-setters
}
```

RootSampleClass:

```
public class RootSampleClass{
  private SampleClassOne classOne;
  private SampleClassTwo classTwo;
  //ommiting getters-setters
}
```

Now I would like to merge two lists into new list of type RootSampleClass based on condition:

```
if(classOneObject.getMyFirstProperty().equals(classTwoObject.getMyOtherProperty()){
 //create new RootSampleClass based on classOneObject and classTwoObject and add it to another collection
}
```

Pseudo code:

```
foreach(one: collectionOne){
 foreach(two: collectionTwo){
    if(one.getMyFirstProperty().equals(two.getMyOtherProperty()){
    collectionThree.add(new RootSampleClass(one, two));
    }
 }
}
```

I am interested in java 8. I would like to have the best performance here that's why I am asking for existing solution without writing custom foreach.

Comment: Would it be more efficient if the two lists were sorted by the property? You might attempt a solution based on that and add that code to your question. A working example showing what you have tried usually yields better answers.

Comment: What happens if two `SampleClassOne` have the same `myFirstProperty` also?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want a custom for each? There is no pre-boxed solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: In short words: I would like to merge two lists of different object types into new third list based on one condition. Normaly I would need to do 2 foreaches and in second foreach do condition - if true we add to another list. But I am thinking if we have now labdas maybe there is faster and more readable solution.

Comment: @Tunaki: my if is custom one - I can compare on one property, two or anything what I want. But what I miss in lambda that in this if I would like to have left and right side object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A direct equivalent to the nested loops is

```
List<RootSampleClass> result = listOne.stream()
    .flatMap(one -> listTwo.stream()
        .filter(two -> one.getMyFirstProperty().equals(two.getMyOtherProperty()))
        .map(two -> new RootSampleClass(one, two)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with an emphasis on *direct equivalent*, which includes the bad performance of doing n×m operations.

A better solution is to convert one of the lists into a data structure supporting an efficient lookup, e.g. a hash map. This consideration is independent of the question which API you use. Since you asked for the Stream API, you can do it like this:

```
Map<String,List<SampleClassOne>> tmp=listOne.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SampleClassOne::getMyFirstProperty));
List<RootSampleClass> result = listTwo.stream()
    .flatMap(two -> tmp.getOrDefault(two.getMyOtherProperty(), Collections.emptyList())
        .stream().map(one -> new RootSampleClass(one, two)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that both solutions will create all possible pairings in case, a property value occurs multiple times within either or both lists. If the property values are unique within each list, like IDs, you can use the following solution:

```
Map<String, SampleClassOne> tmp=listOne.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(SampleClassOne::getMyFirstProperty, Function.identity()));
List<RootSampleClass> result = listTwo.stream()
    .flatMap(two -> Optional.ofNullable(tmp.get(two.getMyOtherProperty()))
            .map(one -> Stream.of(new RootSampleClass(one, two))).orElse(null))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don’t mind potentially performing double lookups, you could replace the last solution with the following more readable code:

```
Map<String, SampleClassOne> tmp=listOne.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(SampleClassOne::getMyFirstProperty, Function.identity()));
List<RootSampleClass> result = listTwo.stream()
    .filter(two -> tmp.containsKey(two.getMyOtherProperty()))
    .map(two -> new RootSampleClass(tmp.get(two.getMyOtherProperty()), two))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```